# Python programming WASD bot movement with pyautogui?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I am trying to program a simple bot using pyautogui for an offline pixel game but I cant seem to make the bot use wasd movement effectively to maneuver over the cotton plant and then click it. it either does not stop, or has some other issue.

```
import pyautogui as pg
import time
import keyboard
import pydirectinput as pd

imageoffset = 25

def checkcotton():
        mypos_x = 950
        mypos_y = 540
        pd.moveTo(mypos_x, mypos_y, 1)
        pos = pg.locateOnScreen('cotton.PNG', confidence=0.8)

        if pos != None:
            print("cotton Found!")

            if pos[0] <= mypos_x + 20 and pos[0] >= mypos_x -20:
                 if pos[1] <= mypos_y + 20 and pos[1] >= mypos_y -20:
                    pd.moveTo(mypos_x, mypos_y, 1)
                    pd.click()

            if pos[0] < 960:
                while pos[0] < 960:
                     pd.press('a')
                     pos = pg.locateOnScreen('cotton.PNG', confidence=0.)

            if pos[0] > 940:
                while pos[0] > 940:
                     pd.press('d')
                     pos = pg.locateOnScreen('cotton.PNG', confidence=0.8)
 
            if pos[1] < 550:
                while pos[1] < 550:
                     pd.press('w')
                     pos = pg.locateOnScreen('cotton.PNG', confidence=0.8)

            if pos[1] > 530:
                while pos[1] > 530:
                     pd.press('s')
                     pos = pg.locateOnScreen('cotton.PNG', confidence=0.8)
 
 
        else: print("Cotton not found")

active = True

while active:
     checkcotton()
     if keyboard.read_key() == "q":
        active = False
```

I have tried using KeyUp and KeyDown but ended up having issues as well.

Comment: Is the problem with both clicking and pressing keys? Please elaborate, since you seem to mention both in your question. Also, since you're using `keyboard`, you don't need to use `pyautogui` for the key pressing functions, if that's what isn't working, so for example, you can try: `keyboard.press_and_release('a')` instead.